# Convergence of solutions of a family of complex differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I have problems understanding the last paragraph of the proof of theorem 4 (on page 10) of this paper(http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol36/vol36pp449-460.pdf). The problem is the following

I have a complex differential equations defined in $\mathbb{D}=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$

\begin{equation}
u''(z)+h_n(z) u(z)=0
\end{equation}

Where $h_n$ are given analytic functions in $\mathbb{D}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N},$ and $h_n \rightarrow L$, where $L$ is analytic in $\mathbb{D}$ (the convergence $h_n \rightarrow L$ is, by the way, locally uniformly. However I dont know if it matters)

And I know  the differential equations $u''(z)+h_n(z) u(z)=0$ have solutions $u_1,u_2,u_3,...$ such that $u_n(0)=1$ and $u_n '(0)=0$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

If $v$ is the solution to
$$u''(z)+L(z) u(z)=0$$

with $v(0)=1$ and $v'(0)=0.$ Why does it follows that
$u_n \rightarrow v$?

It doesn't seem that my basic knowledge of ordinary (real) differential equations will help me here. An explanation or a reference to learn the suitable topics would be highly appreciated.